# What happened to Jamie Maddox's other duplicate?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, messiah-complex

We only see one of Multiple Man's duplicates, the one who goes into the 'Bishop' future.

When this duplicate

> is killed by Layla

Jamie wakes up. Does that mean the other duplicate is already dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other dupe is not already dead (or arguably maybe he is, since he refers to himself as such), but at some point becomes the villain [Cortex](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/James_Madrox_(Cortex)_(Earth-616)), who targets depowered mutants.

> According to Forge after M-Day, all potential futures with mutantkind
> flatlined. However, when the the mutant since M-Day was born two new
> futures popped up. To explore these new futures, Cyclops and Emma
> Frost recruited the help of Madrox the Multiple Man. Madrox and Layla
> Miller traveled to Eagle Plaza in Dallas, Texas to meet with Forge.
> Madrox create two dupes to send into the two remaining mutant futures
> who would recover all the information they could and then die so their
> memories would transfer to Madrox. Cortex was one of these two dupes.
>
> Once this dupe had gained the information about this mutant future he
> attempted to return home. By unknown means he became trapped in a
> vortex where time did not exist.[4] It was here that he was captured
> by Tryp and Anthony Falcone. Tryp and Falcone then made massive
> alterations to him and added cybernetic modification to turn him into
> a doomlock, a being that could alter time without creating divergent
> timelines. He had become Cortex.
>
> Cortex was then sent back in time with instructions to kill specific
> key individuals who progeny would become leaders of the Summers
> Rebellion. To accomplish this, Cortex could mentally control several
> people at once.
>
> Despite being a duplicate of Multiple Man, Cortex can no longer create
> duplicates on his own or be absorbed Madrox Prime. It is unclear if
> this is because of his prolonged separation of Madrox or because of
> the process that turned him into a cyborg.

He has seemingly only appeared in 9 issues, the last of which, X-Factor (Vol 3) #50, is the one that revealed his origin.